# iOS Push Notification, How to broadcast messages

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

I have followed the instruction on http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1 , it worked with me very well.
But, now I have some more concerns which are:

1. How to make the server broadcast notifications to many device not to mine only with registered device token.
2. I want to make my own C# app on windows on server side instead of PHP code.
3. How to make the message increment the badge number?

Comment: All what is in the the following link http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1

Comment: I am asking if there is a way to broadcast messages from server, or I have to send messages to all registered devices individually??

Comment: for question #2, I have found https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp/. but not tested yet

Answer (score 0):

For a simple broadcast solution I would suggest using [urban airship](http://urbanairship.com) which provides all these functions. So you just need to communicate with their API in order to do this.

As for your third question I can tell you that you simply need to add a `+` sign before your badge attribute to increase the badge-number.

Comment: Ah sorry I think that + -thing is a feature of the urbanAirship SDK so if you don't use it, you need to implement this manually.